# django-import-export data import use real value not foreign_id

Tags: python, django

I installed django-import-export app successfully, and I can import data from admin. let's say if I have some database like:

```
name | system_id          id | system
 a   | 1                   1 | system_a
 b   | 1                   2 | system_b
```

so the system_id is a foreign key.
The question is I want to import data from excel:

```
name | system    
 c   | system_c                   
 d   | system_d
```

How can I do to make the data corresponding for each other. So I can use the real name of system in my excel.

Answer (score 0):

You can make custom method in class that inherited "resources.ModelResource" class

```
class ApplicationResource(resources.ModelResource):

    class Meta:
        model = <model name>

    def dehydrate_system(self, instance): #def dehydrate_<field name>(self, instanse) 
        return instance.system.title
```

Comment: Thanks, but still: Column 'system': invalid literal for int() with base 10

Answer (score 0):

I solved it! Just use the ForeignKeyWidget:

```
system_name = fields.Field(column_name='system', attribute='system', widget=ForeignKeyWidget(model, 'system_name'))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a example for insert with one foreign key.

```
    models.py

        from django.db import models

        class Table1(models.Model):
            system = models.CharField(max_length=383)

        class Table2(models.Model):
            name = models.CharField(max_length=383)
            system = models.ForeignKey(Table1, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

You need create a modelResource and override before_import_row for insert data in table1. 
And set ModelResource to admin class.

```
    admin.py
        from .models import Table1,Table2
        from import_export import resources,widgets
        from import_export.fields import Field
        from django.contrib import admin


        class Table2Resource(resources.ModelResource):
            name = Field(column_name='name',attribute='name')
            system_id = Field(column_name='system', attribute='system_id', widget=widgets.ForeignKeyWidget(Table1))

            class Meta:
                model = Table2
                skip_unchanged = True
                fields = ('name','system_id')

            def before_import_row(self,row, **kwargs):
                value = row['system']
                obj = Table1.objects.create(system = value) #create object place
                row['system'] = obj.id # update value to id ob new object


        @admin.register(Table2)
        class Table2Admin(ImportExportModelAdmin,admin.ModelAdmin):
            resource_class = Table2Resource
```

This is all.